# Keybind action being run at start but not from actual key press

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I'm coding a game for my final project in Java, our teacher provided us with a Board class that is a component that allows us to place and remove pegs on a virtual game board instead of having to code one ourselves. I'm trying to add Key Binding to the Board component but the action I want performed on key press is happening when I run the program but It won't run when I type a Key.

The board class already has a method for getting the position clicked on the component and I think this might be interfering with my Code but I'm not sure.

This is my game class where I tried to add keybinding

```
package rpgGame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class RPGGame
{
    public static final GameWorld WORLD_MAP = new GameWorld();
    public static Board LOCAL_MAP = new Board(20,50);

    public static List<Mobile> allMobs = new ArrayList<Mobile>();
    public static final Player PLAYER = new Player();

    public static int xIndex = ((GameWorld.WORLD_SIZE-1)/2) - (50/2);
    public static int yIndex = ((GameWorld.WORLD_SIZE-1)/2) - (20/2);

    public static boolean boardUpdate = true;

    public enum Direction {RIGHT,LEFT,UP,DOWN}

    private static final String MOVE_PLAYER_UP = "move up";
    private static final String MOVE_PLAYER_LEFT = "move left";
    private static final String MOVE_PLAYER_RIGHT = "move right";
    private static final String MOVE_PLAYER_DOWN = "move down";

    public static final Thread SYNC_BOARD = new Thread()
    {
        public synchronized void run()
        {
            while (boardUpdate)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
                    {
                        if (WORLD_MAP.isOccupied(i+xIndex, j+yIndex)) 
                        {
                            LOCAL_MAP.putPeg(Color.RED, j, i);
                            System.out.println("Successfully Updated");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            LOCAL_MAP.putPeg(Color.GRAY, j,i);

                        }
                    }
                }
                boardUpdate = false;
            }
        }
    };

    public RPGGame()
    {
        generateMobs(200);
        placeMobs();
        placePlayer();
        SYNC_BOARD.run();

        LOCAL_MAP.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), MOVE_PLAYER_UP);
        LOCAL_MAP.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), MOVE_PLAYER_UP);
        LOCAL_MAP.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), MOVE_PLAYER_LEFT);
        LOCAL_MAP.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), MOVE_PLAYER_LEFT);
        LOCAL_MAP.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), MOVE_PLAYER_RIGHT);
        LOCAL_MAP.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0), MOVE_PLAYER_RIGHT);
        LOCAL_MAP.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), MOVE_PLAYER_DOWN);
        LOCAL_MAP.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0), MOVE_PLAYER_DOWN);

        LOCAL_MAP.getActionMap().put(MOVE_PLAYER_UP, new MoveAction(Direction.UP));
        LOCAL_MAP.getActionMap().put(MOVE_PLAYER_LEFT, new MoveAction(Direction.LEFT));
        LOCAL_MAP.getActionMap().put(MOVE_PLAYER_RIGHT, new MoveAction(Direction.RIGHT));
        LOCAL_MAP.getActionMap().put(MOVE_PLAYER_DOWN, new MoveAction(Direction.DOWN));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new RPGGame();
    }

    public static void generateMobs(int numOfMobs)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<numOfMobs; i++)
        {
            allMobs.add(new Mobile());
        }
    }

    public static void generateMobs()
    {
        int numOfMobs  = (int)(Math.random()*500);
        for (int i=0;i<numOfMobs; i++)
        {
            allMobs.add(new Mobile());
        }
    }

    public static void placeMobs()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<allMobs.size(); i++)
        {
            //i is used as a placeholder value for points until I create a random number generator.
            WORLD_MAP.placeCharacter(i, i,allMobs.get(i));
            allMobs.get(i).setLocation(i, i);
        }
    }

    public static void placePlayer()
    {
        WORLD_MAP.placeCharacter(249, 249, PLAYER);
        PLAYER.setLocation(249, 249);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        Direction direction;

        public MoveAction(Direction direction)
        {
            if (direction.equals(Direction.RIGHT))
            {
                int x = PLAYER.getX();
                int y = PLAYER.getY();
                WORLD_MAP.moveCharacter(x+1, y, x, y);
                PLAYER.move(1, 0);
                boardUpdate = true;
                System.out.println("MOVE RIGHT");
            }
            if (direction.equals(Direction.LEFT))
            {
                int x = PLAYER.getX();
                int y = PLAYER.getY();
                WORLD_MAP.moveCharacter(x, y, x-1, y);
                PLAYER.move(-1, 0);
                boardUpdate = true;
                System.out.println("MOVE LEFT");
            }
            if (direction.equals(Direction.UP))
            {
                int x = PLAYER.getX();
                int y = PLAYER.getY();
                WORLD_MAP.moveCharacter(x, y, x, y+1);
                PLAYER.move(0, 1);
                boardUpdate = true;
                System.out.println("MOVE UP");
            }
            if (direction.equals(Direction.DOWN))
            {
                int x = PLAYER.getX();
                int y = PLAYER.getY();
                WORLD_MAP.moveCharacter(x, y, x, y-1);
                PLAYER.move(0, -1);
                boardUpdate = true;
                System.out.println("MOVE DOWN");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

This is the Board class

```
package rpgGame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

/**  Board GUI for implementation with various games
 *   Author: Kirill Levin, Troy Vasiga, Chris Ingram
 */

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Board extends JPanel
{
    private static final int X_DIM = 60;
    private static final int Y_DIM = 60;
    private static final int X_OFFSET = 30;
    private static final int Y_OFFSET = 30;
    private static final double MIN_SCALE = 0.25;
    private static final int GAP = 10;
    private static final int FONT_SIZE = 16;

    // Grid colours
    private static final Color GRID_COLOR_A = new Color(153,255,102);
    private static final Color GRID_COLOR_B = new Color(136,255,77);

    private Color[][] grid;
    private Point lastClick;  // How the mouse handling thread communicates 
    // to the board where the last click occurred
    private String message = "";
    private int numLines = 0;
    private double[][] line = new double[4][100];  // maximum number of lines is 100
    private int columns, rows;

    private int originalWidth;
    private int originalHeight;
    private double scale;

    /** A constructor to build a 2D board.
     */
    public Board (int rows, int columns)
    {
        super( true );
        JFrame boardFrame = new JFrame( "Board game" );

        this.columns = columns;
        this.rows = rows;
        originalWidth = 2*X_OFFSET+X_DIM*columns;
        originalHeight = 2*Y_OFFSET+Y_DIM*rows+GAP+FONT_SIZE;

        this.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( originalWidth, originalHeight ) );

        boardFrame.setResizable(true);

        this.grid = new Color[columns][rows];

        this.addMouseListener(
                new MouseInputAdapter() 
                {
                    /** A method that is called when the mouse is clicked
                     */
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
                    { 
                        int x = (int)e.getPoint().getX();
                        int y = (int)e.getPoint().getY();

                        // We need to by synchronized to the parent class so we can wake
                        // up any threads that might be waiting for us
                        synchronized(Board.this) 
                        {
                            int curX = (int)Math.round(X_OFFSET*scale);
                            int curY = (int)Math.round(Y_OFFSET*scale);
                            int nextX = (int)Math.round((X_OFFSET+X_DIM*grid.length)*scale);
                            int nextY = (int)Math.round((Y_OFFSET+Y_DIM*grid[0].length)*scale);

                            // Subtract one from high end so clicks on the black edge
                            // don't yield a row or column outside of board because of
                            // the way the coordinate is calculated.
                            if (x >= curX && y >= curY && x < nextX && y < nextY)
                            {
                                lastClick = new Point(y,x);
                                // Notify any threads that would be waiting for a mouse click
                                Board.this.notifyAll() ;
                            } /* if */
                        } /* synchronized */
                    } /* mouseClicked */
                } /* anonymous MouseInputAdapater */
                );

        boardFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        boardFrame.setContentPane( this );
        boardFrame.pack();
        boardFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /** A constructor to build a 1D board.
     */
    public Board (int cols)
    {
        this(1, cols);
    }

    private void paintText(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor( this.getBackground() );
        g.setFont(new Font(g.getFont().getFontName(), Font.ITALIC+Font.BOLD, (int)(Math.round(FONT_SIZE*scale))));

        int x = (int)Math.round(X_OFFSET*scale);
        int y = (int)Math.round((Y_OFFSET+Y_DIM*grid[0].length)*scale + GAP  ) ;

        g.fillRect(x,y, this.getSize().width, (int)Math.round(GAP+FONT_SIZE*scale) );
        g.setColor( Color.black );
        g.drawString(message, x, y + (int)Math.round(FONT_SIZE*scale));
    }

    private void paintGrid(Graphics g)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.grid.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.grid[i].length; j++)
            {    
                if ((i%2 == 0 && j%2 != 0) || (i%2 != 0 && j%2 == 0))
                    g.setColor(GRID_COLOR_A);
                else
                    g.setColor(GRID_COLOR_B);
                int curX = (int)Math.round((X_OFFSET+X_DIM*i)*scale);
                int curY = (int)Math.round((Y_OFFSET+Y_DIM*j)*scale);
                int nextX = (int)Math.round((X_OFFSET+X_DIM*(i+1))*scale);
                int nextY = (int)Math.round((Y_OFFSET+Y_DIM*(j+1))*scale);
                int deltaX = nextX-curX; 
                int deltaY = nextY-curY;

                g.fillRect( curX, curY, deltaX, deltaY );
                Color curColour = this.grid[i][j];
                if (curColour != null) // Draw pegs if they exist
                {
                    g.setColor(curColour);
                    g.fillOval(curX+deltaX/4, curY+deltaY/4, deltaX/2, deltaY/2);
                }
            }
        }
        ((Graphics2D) g).setStroke( new BasicStroke(0.5f) );
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        int curX = (int)Math.round(X_OFFSET*scale);
        int curY = (int)Math.round(Y_OFFSET*scale);
        int nextX = (int)Math.round((X_OFFSET+X_DIM*grid.length)*scale);
        int nextY = (int)Math.round((Y_OFFSET+Y_DIM*grid[0].length)*scale);
        g.drawRect(curX, curY, nextX-curX, nextY-curY);
    }

    private void drawLine(Graphics g)
    {
        for (int i =0; i < numLines; i++ ) 
        {
            ((Graphics2D) g).setStroke( new BasicStroke( 5.0f*(float)scale) );
            g.drawLine( (int)Math.round((X_OFFSET+X_DIM/2.0+line[0][i]*X_DIM)*scale), 
                    (int)Math.round((Y_OFFSET+Y_DIM/2.0+line[1][i]*Y_DIM)*scale), 
                    (int)Math.round((X_OFFSET+X_DIM/2.0+line[2][i]*X_DIM)*scale), 
                    (int)Math.round((Y_OFFSET+Y_DIM/2.0+line[3][i]*Y_DIM)*scale) );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Convert a String to the corresponding Color defaulting to Black 
     * with an invald input
     */
    /*private Color convertColour( String theColour )
    {
        for( int i=0; i<COLOUR_NAMES.length; i++ )
        {
            if( COLOUR_NAMES[i].equalsIgnoreCase( theColour ) )
                return COLOURS[i];
        }

        return DEFAULT_COLOUR;
    }*/


    /** The method that draws everything
     */
    public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) 
    {
        this.setScale();
        this.paintGrid(g);
        this.drawLine(g);
        this.paintText(g);
    }

    public void setScale()
    {
        double width = (0.0+this.getSize().width) / this.originalWidth;
        double height = (0.0+this.getSize().height) / this.originalHeight;
        this.scale = Math.max( Math.min(width,height), MIN_SCALE ); 
    }

    /** Sets the message to be displayed under the board
     */
    public void displayMessage(String theMessage)
    {
        message = theMessage;
        this.repaint();
    }


    /** This method will save the value of the colour of the peg in a specific 
     * spot.  theColour is restricted to 
     *   "yellow", "blue", "cyan", "green", "pink", "white", "red", "orange"  
     * Otherwise the colour black will be used. 
     */
    public void putPeg(Color colour, int row, int col)
    {
        this.grid[col][row] = colour;
        this.repaint();
    }

    /** Same as putPeg above but for 1D boards
     */
    public void putPeg(Color colour, int col)
    {
        this.putPeg(colour, 0, col );
    }

    /** Remove a peg from the gameboard.
     */
    public void removePeg(int row, int col)
    {
        this.grid[col][row] = null;
        repaint();
    }

    /** Same as removePeg above but for 1D boards
     */
    public void removePeg(int col)
    {
        this.grid[col][0] = null;
        repaint();
    }

    /** Draws a line on the board using the given co-ordinates as endpoints
     */
    public void drawLine(double row1, double col1, double row2, double col2)
    {
        this.line[0][numLines]=col1;
        this.line[1][numLines]=row1;
        this.line[2][numLines]=col2;
        this.line[3][numLines]=row2;
        this.numLines++;
        repaint();
    }

    /** Removes one line from a board given the co-ordinates as endpoints
     * If there is no such line, nothing happens
     * If multiple lines, all copies are removed
     */

    public void removeLine(int row1, int col1, int row2, int col2) 
    {
        int curLine = 0;
        while (curLine < this.numLines) 
        {
            // Check for either endpoint being specified first in our line table
            if ( (line[0][curLine] == col1 && line[1][curLine] == row1 &&
                    line[2][curLine] == col2 && line[3][curLine] == row2)   || 
                    (line[2][curLine] == col1 && line[3][curLine] == row1 &&
                    line[0][curLine] == col2 && line[1][curLine] == row2) )
            {
                // found a matching line: overwrite with the last one
                numLines--;
                line[0][curLine] = line[0][numLines];
                line[1][curLine] = line[1][numLines];
                line[2][curLine] = line[2][numLines];
                line[3][curLine] = line[3][numLines];
                curLine--; // perhaps the one we copied is also a match
            }
            curLine++;

        }
        repaint();
    }

    /** Waits for user to click somewhere and then returns the click.
     */
    public Point getClick()
    {
        Point returnedClick = null;
        synchronized(this) {
            lastClick = null;
            while (lastClick == null)
            {
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    // We'll never call Thread.interrupt(), so just consider
                    // this an error.
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(-1) ;
                } /* try */
            }

            int x = (int)Math.floor((lastClick.getY()-X_OFFSET*scale)/X_DIM/scale);
            int y = (int)Math.floor((lastClick.getX()-Y_OFFSET*scale)/Y_DIM/scale);

            // Put this into a new object to avoid a possible race.
            returnedClick = new Point(x,y);
        }
        return returnedClick;
    }

    /** Same as getClick above but for 1D boards
     */
    public double getPosition()
    {
        return this.getClick().getY();
    }

    public int getColumns()
    {
        return this.columns;
    }

    public int getRows()
    {
        return this.rows;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should ask the TAs who wrote this how they intended for you to add key bindings to `Board`. If this is for a class, hoping the code is fine and you're just using it wrong (not to suggest fault on your part, not all teachers/classes provide good documentation on how to use their code, just like in real life!).

Comment: Note that in addition to the issue that I mention in my answer, your teacher's Board class's paintComponent override does not call the super's method within it, and this can cause significant problems as it breaks the painting chain.

Comment: Unfortunately 'Board' came from [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~tmjvasig/ibmtalk/), which is not the school I go to. I'm in high school and I'm not sure our teacher knows how key bindings would work with this class either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're shooting yourself in the foot with that thread code -- you're calling **run()** not **start()** on it

```
SYNC_BOARD.run();
```

This will run on the Swing event thread and risks completely freezing your GUI.

As a general rule, you should almost never extend Thread but rather implement Runnable, but regardless, don't use that Thread code -- Instead use a Swing Timer since your code has no breaks in it, no Thread.sleeps and it will make your CPU awfully busy, and the Swing Timer will help make sure that your code obeys Swing threading rules.

Also your MoveAction is wrong. Most of that code should go in the actionPerformed method. The constructor should just set the direction field and that's it.

Something like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {
    Direction direction;

    public MoveAction(Direction direction) {
        // this is the only code the constructor should have!
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // use direction to help make move in here
    }
}
```

Understand that this is likely causing some major problems, since the constructor is called on program creation (hence your key bindings "work" when the program starts), but it's the actionPerformed that actually gets called when the right key is pressed.

Comment: That made it work! I feel like an idiot that I put my logic in the constructor now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm also going to change it so that everytime a move action happens an `UpdateBoard` method will be called to accomplish the same thing that `SYNC_BOARD` did.